# How interpretate the graphic with the main frequencies of a mixed signal?

Tags: python, fft, dft

I was given a plot from a txt file. The goal is to filter the signal.
I plot a graphic to give the ck (frequencies of the signal), I got a result i didn´t expect.

```
def dft(a): # Esta função serve para calcular os ck dos correspondentes coeficientes de Fourier 
    N = len(a) 
    c = np.zeros(N//2 +1,complex) 
    n = np.arange(0,N) 
    for k in range(N//2 + 1): 
        c[k] = sum(a*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pik*n/N)) 
    return c 

c=dft(a) 
plt.plot(abs(c)) 
plt.show() 
print(max(c))
```

Image of graph :

[image]

Comment: def dft(a): # Esta função serve para calcular os ck dos correspondentes coeficientes de Fourier
    N = len(a)
    c = np.zeros(N//2 +1,complex)
    n = np.arange(0,N)
    for k in range(N//2 + 1):
        c[k] = sum(a*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*k*n/N))
        
    return c

c=dft(a)
plt.plot(abs(c))
plt.show()
print(max(c))

Comment: You should edit the original question, and add this data there, properly indented with 4 spaces per line. You also need to add some tic-marks, values, and label the x and y axes  so we know what is being measured against what. See [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm) for some `MatPlotLib` formatting tips.

Comment: Please also show in the OP, or add a link to, some or all of the data in the original text file.

Comment: Is `sum(anp.exp(-1j*2*np.pik*n/N))` above supposed to be `anp.exp()` as in `numpy_wrapper` or `np.exp()` as in `eulers_number^x`?

Comment: the labels are x: k which is proportional to frequencies and y: ck (fourier coeficients) and the main frequencies of the signal

Comment: Why didn’t you expect that? What is the data? The explanation is given by how the original signal was obtained. I don’t see how this question is related to the topics of Stack Overflow. Maybe ask in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/?